# Mocking/Stubbing an Object of a class that implements arrayaccess in PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit, arrayaccess

Here is the constructor of the class I am writing a test suite for (it extends mysqli):

```
function __construct(Config $c)
{
    // store config file
    $this->config = $c;

    // do mysqli constructor
    parent::__construct(
        $this->config['db_host'],
        $this->config['db_user'],
        $this->config['db_pass'],
        $this->config['db_dbname']
    );
}
```

The `Config` class passed to the constructor implements the `arrayaccess` interface built in to php:

```
class Config implements arrayaccess{...}
```

How do I mock/stub the `Config` object? Which should I use and why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you can easily create a `Config` instance from an array, that would be my preference. While you want to test your units in isolation where practical, simple collaborators such as `Config` should be safe enough to use in the test. The code to set it up will probably be easier to read and write (less error-prone) than the equivalent mock object.

```
$configValues = array(
    'db_host' => '...',
    'db_user' => '...',
    'db_pass' => '...',
    'db_dbname' => '...',
);
$config = new Config($configValues);
```

That being said, you mock an object implementing [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) just as you would any other object.

```
$config = $this->getMock('Config', array('offsetGet'));
$config->expects($this->any())
       ->method('offsetGet')
       ->will($this->returnCallback(
           function ($key) use ($configValues) {
               return $configValues[$key];
           }
       );
```

You can also use `at` to impose a specific order of access, but you'll make the test very brittle that way.

Comment: You could even do it easire, but using an array :-)

Answer (score 2):

8 years after the question asked, 5 years after it was first answered I had the same question and came to a similar conclusion. This is what I did, which is basically the same as the second part of David's accepted answer, except I'm using a later version of PHPUnit.

Basically you can mock the `ArrayAccess` interface methods. Just need to remember that you probably want to mock both `offsetGet` and `offsetExists` (you should always check an array key exists before you use it otherwise you could encounter an `E_NOTICE` error and unpredictable behaviour in your code if it doesn't exist).

```
$thingyWithArrayAccess = $this->createMock(ThingyWithArrayAccess::class);

$thingyWithArrayAccess->method('offsetGet')
     ->with('your-offset-here')
     ->willReturn('test-value-1');

$thingyWithArrayAccess->method('offsetExists')
     ->with($'your-offset-here')
     ->willReturn(true);
```

Of course, you could have a real array in the test to work with, like

```
$theArray = [
    'your-offset-here-1' => 'your-mock-value-for-offset-1',
];

$thingyWithArrayAccess = $this->createMock(ThingyWithArrayAccess::class);

$thingyWithArrayAccess->method('offsetGet')
     ->willReturnCallback(
          function ($offset) use ($theArray) {
              return $theArray[$offset];
          }
     );

$thingyWithArrayAccess->method('offsetExists')
     ->willReturnCallback(
          function ($offset) use ($theArray) {
              return array_key_exists($offset, $theArray);
          }
     );
```

Comment: Wow, what a blast from the past! It's been nearly as long since I've even worked in PHP.